# Spring JPA 2.0 Repository / Factory not working

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I'm trying to implement a custom java Spring JPA repository, as described in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations).
It seems that my spring config insists on creating the repositories in the standard way, instead of using the given MyRepositoryFactoryBean, giving me

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.myapp.repository.impl.DocumentRepositoryImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myapp.repository.impl.DocumentRepositoryImpl.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myapp.repository.impl.DocumentRepositoryImpl.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2730)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2004)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
```

I'm using Spring 3.2.2-RELEASE and spring-data-jpa-1.3.2-RELEASE, which is the latest if I'm correct. Here's my spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="spring-repository-config.xml"/>
<import resource="spring-security-config.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.web.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.webservice.controller"/>
```

And here's the spring-repository-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">

<repositories base-package="com.myapp.repository"
     factory-class="com.myapp.repository.impl.MyRepositoryFactoryBean"/>
<!-- entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"  -->
```

If've added debug breakpoints in all the methods of the com.myapp.repository.impl.MyRepositoryFactoryBean class, but these were not called.

The basic interface, just like in the example

```
package com.myapp.repository.impl;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
```

The base implementation:

```
package com.myapp.repository.impl;

@NoRepositoryBean
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

private EntityManager entityManager;

public MyRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(domainClass, entityManager);

    // This is the recommended method for accessing inherited class dependencies.
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
    // implementation goes here
}   
}
```

And the factory:

```
package com.myapp.repository.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new MyRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
}

private static class MyRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        return new MyRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
        // to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
        return MyRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
}
}
```

My repositories interfaces are defines as:

```
package com.myapp.repository;

public interface DocumentRepository { // extends MyRepository<Document, Long>

public Document findByDocumentHash(String hashCode);

public Document findById(long id);

}
```

And the implementation is

```
package com.myapp.repository.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class DocumentRepositoryImpl<Document, ID extends Serializable> extends MyRepositoryImpl<Document, Serializable> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DocumentRepositoryImpl(Class<Document> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
    }
```

And I use these repositories as autowired refernces in my controllers:

```
package com.myapp.web.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/documents")
public class DocumentController {

@Autowired
private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.documentRepository. ...
}
```

I've looked at various resources on the web like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140867/cant-autowire-repositories-created-by-jparepositoryfactorybean), but I can't tell the difference with my code. Any hints are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need default constructor for `com.myapp.repository.impl.DocumentRepositoryImpl`

```
public DocumentRepositoryImpl(){}
```

Spring first instantiate the beans that you declare in the app context (in your case) by calling the default constructor( no parameters ) and than uses setters to inject other beans.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer. But the parent class, SimpleJpaRepository, has 2 constructors, each with 2 arguments that must be provided. [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:58)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.<init>(SimpleJpaRepository.java:91)
at com.myapp.repository.impl.MyRepositoryImpl.<init>(MyRepositoryImpl.java:18)
at com.myapp.repository.impl.DocumentRepositoryImpl.<init>

Comment: And the PersonRepoImpl class here (http://hvanhove.blogspot.nl/2013/03/generic-repo-for-all-repositories.html) doesn't have a default constructor either.